# django 2 custom jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler

Tags: django, python-3.x, jwt, auth0, django-2.0

To validate the jwt token of auth0 in django, I use the following code in settings.py

```
def jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler(payload):

    return 'authuser'

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USERNAME_HANDLER': jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler,
    'JWT_PUBLIC_KEY': PUBLIC_KEY,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'RS256',
    'JWT_AUDIENCE': API_IDENTIFIER,
    'JWT_ISSUER': JWT_ISSUER,
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'Bearer',
}
```

where authuser is the username. So Instead of writing it directly I want to receive it in request header and pass it. Please help me in customising this function - jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler in such a way. TIA

Answer (score 2):

```
def jwt_get_username_from_payload_handler(user):

    return {
        'username': user.username,
        'email': user.email,
        'is_superuser': user.is_superuser,
    }
```

you can use this function

Comment: Is there a way to do the same without sqlite in mongodb

Comment: Where would you put this function?